# Sqlalchemy Does Not Emit Correct SQL for MSSQL GETDATE() server default

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have the following declarative SQL class:

```
class Test(Base):
    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default='GETDATE()')
```

But using Base.metadata.create_all(engine) causes the following SQL to be emitted for the SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP:

```
[SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GETDATE()',
```

An example for how GETDATE should be emitted from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_getdate.asp:

```
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

I have tried using func.getdate instead of 'GETDATE()' as the server_default, but get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<type 'basestring'>' or
 '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression.  ClauseElement'>' or
 '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause'>',
  got '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression._FunctionGenerator'>'
```

SQLAlchemy version: 0.9.6
Pyodbc version: 3.0.5
Python version: 2.7

How do I get SQLAlchemy to emit to correct SQL to set the server default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to define the server default using the `text()` function of SQLAlchemy:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=sa.text("GETDATE()"))
```

This will then correctly emit the server default:

```
[SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
```

This is documented here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#server-side-defaults